# Heroku over Network Solutions, web developer to convince boss

Tags: heroku, hosting

I have a critical meeting tomorrow and I need to convince my operations manager to let our web team leverage Heroku vs our current solution, Network Solutions.

Network Solutions is pretty locked down. They offer rails, but with a locked set of usable gems and the version of rails is pretty old. I am also not productive in PHP. We do have "large windows" hosting with them, but they are running IIS 6 and I would want to use MVC. I am not saying it is not usable, there are work arounds.. but why bother with the headache? Just switch to Heroku and call it a day.

Does anyone have any experience with pricing on Heroku? We do B2B applications and see very small amounts of traffic, at best we would see 5000 hits a month.

Pushing from GIT eliminates making "small changes" to the live site via ftp, and not following up on the local version. (massive time sink / headache)

Heroku gives EACH project it's own "VPS" essentially, so if one of our apps bears fruit it can scale with out taking out a whole server.

How easy it is to actually scale? Would I be wrong to say that it is easy as a "push of a button?"

It's going to be around for a while right? I am using the argument that Heroku is "pay as you go", and since our apps are very low traffic our costs will be very low. But, I understand that this makes for an un-sustainable business model- like how Google App Engine had to re-evaluate it's payment structure. Would Heroku ever go to a "shared" hosting plan for apps like ours? Just so we are not getting a free ride (I'd like to support the platform).

One of the concerns is getting "another" hosting environment, when we have been trying to consolidate. Unfortunately they chose Network Solutions before I got there.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go at it from this angle. Explain to your boss that should your business require a certain feature that you currently don't have, being able to add gems at will to a Heroku platform will allow the extensibility and give you options for better serving customers and scale with the business's future growth, whereas NS is very limiting, causing bottlenecks and problems that your business will be hurt by, because it will result in lost productivity for you and will not support the architecture you'll need to stay ahead in the future. Talk in business terms that will make sense to your boss, and many times they will be able to understand why you want to do a certain thing. Help it relate to the strategic objectives that you are likely to undertake in the future. Paint a big picture. Draw out some scenarios that make your point in a "how does this affect the bottom line/hassles for him."